# Tradingview delete line on condition

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to delete a line on condition after it has been plotted.

So Im going through 2 steps;

1. Plot lines ONLY in the last X bars
2. Delete lines if a condition is met.

For the second case, it is not detecting any lines on the chart, I'm trying to put up a label everytime a line has been found however the labels do not plot. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
//@version=4
study(title='Testing', overlay=true, max_lines_count=30)

showLines = input(title="Show Lines ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

if showLines == true and barstate.islast

    line bullLine1 = na //bull line
    
    BARS_BACK = 20

    //Loop to plot a line
    for i = BARS_BACK to 0                
        bullishcase = close[i+1] > high[i+2]

        if bullishcase
            bullLine1 := line.new(x1=bar_index[i + 2], y1=high[i + 2], x2=bar_index[i], y2=high[i + 2], extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)

    //Loop to delete a line
    for i = BARS_BACK to 0
        if not na(bullLine1[i])
            label.new(bar_index[i], high[i], "Line 1 found" )
```

I tried another approach to this issue by using this solution:
[How to delete a line when price breaks it in pine script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051104/how-to-delete-a-line-when-price-breaks-it-in-pine-script)
However, it works most of the times but sometimes it gives me the error "too many drawings. cannot clean the oldest". I'm not sure how I can go about that

Comment: How about making it transparent in those areas?

Comment: I tried using plots but the outcome I got is very different compared to using line. I might be doing it wrong though

Answer (score 2):

As realtime bars close, this will delete lines outside the last 20 bars.

```
//@version=4
study(title='Testing', overlay=true, max_lines_count=30)

showLines = input(title="Show Lines ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

BARS_BACK = 20
line bullLine1 = na //bull line
if showLines == true and barstate.islast
    //Loop to plot a line
    for i = BARS_BACK to 0                
        bullishcase = close[i+1] > high[i+2]

        if bullishcase
            bullLine1 := line.new(x1=bar_index[i + 2], y1=high[i + 2], x2=bar_index[i], y2=high[i + 2], extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)

// If there is one, delete line outside the allowed set of BARS_BACK bars.
line.delete(bullLine1[BARS_BACK + 1])
```